# Beginner Javascript error with getAttribute

Tags: javascript, getattribute

I've searched quite a bit on both google and stackoverflow, but a lack of knowledge on how to ask the question (or even if I'm asking the right question at all) is making it hard to find pertinent information.

I have a simple block of code that I am experimenting with to teach myself javascript.

```
var studio = document.getElementById('studio');
var contact = document.getElementById('contact');
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var navLinks = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');

var title = navLinks.getAttribute('title');
```

I want to grab the title attribute from the links in the element with the ID 'nav'.

Whenever I look at the debugger, it tells me that `Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getAttribute'`

I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

The nodetype and nodevalue for navLinks comes back as undefined, which I believe may be part of the problem, but I'm so new to this that I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Don't use *getAttribute* for standard HTML attributes, use the related DOM property, so `var title = navLinks[0].title`. It's faster, less to type and removes the browser differences in *getAttribute*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) method returns an array of objects. So you need to loop through this array in order to get individual elements and their attributes:

```
var navLinks = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    var link = navLinks[i];
    var title = link.title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Very much appreciated, as I've been sitting here for quite a while before I decided to sign up here and seek some answers.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList, which is **not** an Array. See http://www.sitepoint.com/a-collection-is-not-an-array/

Answer (score 1):

Calling `nav.getElementsByTagName('a')` returns list of objects. And that list doesn't have getAttribute() method. You must call it on ONE object.

When you do:

```
navLinks[0].getAttribute('title')
```

then it should work - you will get title of the first matched element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var navLinks = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns multiple elements (hence `Elements`), because there can be multiple elements on one page with the same tag name.  A `NodeList` (which is a collection of nodes as returned by `getElementsByTagName`) does not have a `getAttribute` method.

You need to access the property of the element that you actually need.  My guess is that this will be the first element you find.

```
var title = navLinks[0].getAttribute('title');
```